# How to Use Absolute Pricing for Custom Options Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

Please open below link and check "Interested in Embroidery" checkbox.

http://superbuniforms.com/magento/medical-lab-coat-unisex-sky-blue.html

Some options will show which are product custom options. Here, two options have price "Logo Creation Fee" and "Embroidery Logo Charge". When I select all options and add to cart. On cart page, If I increase product quantity, all option's price increase with quantity. But I want that when product quantity increase, only "Embroidery Logo Charge ($35)" custom option is vary with quantity not "Logo Creation Fee($300)".

Example  : If product price is $50 and product have two custom options like- "Logo Creation Fee ($300)" and "Embroidery Logo Charge($35)". When we add product(quantity 1) in cart with both custom options (subtotal is $385).

Subtotal is: (product price ($50) + Logo Creation Fee ($300) + Embroidery Logo Charge($35)) * 1 = $385

Now, we increase product quantity (2) then subtotal is :

Subtotal is: (product price ($50) + Logo Creation Fee ($300) + Embroidery Logo Charge($35)) * 2 = $770

But I want to change in subtotal. I want subtotal like this :

Subtotal is: ((product price ($50) + Embroidery Logo Charge($35)) * 2) + Logo Creation Fee ($300) = $470 ($170 + $300)

"Logo Creation Fee ($300)" not vary with quantity, add only one quantity for one product.

Means Product's "Unit Price" display without custom option's price.

Reference URL (Opencart) : https://www.superbuniforms.com/hospital-uniforms/lab-coats/medical-lab-coat-women-sky-blue

Please add product with options and check cart.

Please suggest.

Comment: @7ochem sir, please suggest how to implement.

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-absolute-price.html
extension should work out for you,